# Button cannot be clicked when timer is running C#

Tags: c#, button, timer, wpf-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have made an application to have a marquee text with an exit button. The button works fine when the timer is disabled but it cannot be clicked once the timer is enabled.
Can anyone please help me? I tried researching online but no answer seems to be available, thank you! :)

this is the code that I have

```
    public FORM_ENTRY()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LabelWelcome.Text = "Welcome! Welkom! Selamat Datang! Wilkommen!";
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        LabelCheckedIn.Visible = false;
        LabelEnjoy.Visible = false;
    }

    private void StartScroll()
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(LabelWelcome.Text + " ");

        while (true)
        {
            char ch = sb[sb.Length - 1];
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
            sb.Insert(0, ch);
            LabelWelcome.Text = sb.ToString();
            LabelWelcome.Refresh();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartScroll();
    }

    private void ButtonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to be able to produce a verifiable problem.

Comment: StartScroll is running in your ThreadUI. It has an infinite loop. Move StartScroll to a separate thread.

Comment: You don't need another thread, you already have a timer. Change `sb` in the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [DispatchTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), it will run on a separate thread, and the event will be triggered on the UI thread, so you will be able to modify your UI

```
private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;


public FORM_ENTRY()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LabelWelcome.Text = "Welcome! Welkom! Selamat Datang! Wilkommen!";
    LabelCheckedIn.Visible = false;
    LabelEnjoy.Visible = false;

    // Initialize Dispatcher
    dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    // Five seconds delay
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(LabelWelcome.Text);        
    char ch = sb[sb.Length - 1];
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
    sb.Insert(0, ch);
    LabelWelcome.Text = sb.ToString();
}

private void ButtonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```